# Opencart Get Category URL based from Category ID

Tags: php, opencart

I'm working with a template in opencart where I am manually creating the links.

The category links on the storefront are subject to change to SEO friendly urls, so I dont want to be copying the urls that look like this `index.php?route=product/category&path=100` if I'm going to have to go back and change it later.

I was wondering if there is some PHP code that I could use to somehow create a link based off of the category ID.

Lets say if my category id is `152`

I want to be able to use PHP in my `<a href"#">` to say something like this:

`<a href="<?php get link for category '152' ?>">`

ofcourse I know that isnt the code. But does anyone know a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to use the URL rewriter class, passing the category ID into it

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=152'); ?>">
```

Comment: is there any way to use a similar method to query the seo-friendly url?

Comment: @Allen - Just search the `url_alias` table for `category_id=152` in the `query` column, and the `keyword` column will have the keyword